# <a> tag appears in the wrong position in Chrome

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, razor

I have a repeating partial view in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that is showing up incorrectly in certain circumstances in Chrome. It's not happening in any other browser, and I'm at a loss to figure out what's going on.

My razor code is pretty straightforward -- just a `foreach` loop that calls `@Html.Partial()`. I'm going to skip it for now in the interest of saving space, but the HTML it produces looks like this:

```
<div id="dataDisplay">
    <div id="dataRow39" class="list">
        <a href="/StateAssociation/Edit/39" class="x-small action edit-button" data-hba-ajax="true" data-hba-method="get" data-hba-target="#dataRow39" data-hba-mode="replace">Edit</a>
        <span class="normal">AAA Test 1</span>
        <span class="large">Test Description 1</span>
        <a href="/StateAssociation/Delete/39" class="delete-button" data-hba-ajax="true" data-hba-method="get" data-hba-target="#dataRow39" data-hba-mode="replace">X</a>
        </div>
        <div id="dataRow1" class="list">
            <a href="/StateAssociation/Edit/1" class="x-small action edit-button" data-hba-ajax="true" data-hba-method="get" data-hba-target="#dataRow1" data-hba-mode="replace">Edit</a>
        <span class="normal">AHBA</span>
        <span class="large">Arkansas Home Builders Association</span>
        <a href="/StateAssociation/Delete/1" class="delete-button" data-hba-ajax="true" data-hba-method="get" data-hba-target="#dataRow1" data-hba-mode="replace">X</a>
    </div>
    . . .
</div>
```

And the page itself looks like this:

[image: Initial page view]

When users click the "Edit" link, I use an AJAX call to replace a single `div` with a different partial view that has `input` elements for data-entry. That `div` also has a cancel button that triggers another AJAX call back to the original partial view. That produces nearly identical HTML, but one element gets positioned wrong.

```
<div id="dataDisplay">
        <div id="dataRow39" class="list">
        <a href="/StateAssociation/Edit/39" class="x-small action edit-button" data-hba-ajax="true" data-hba-method="get" data-hba-target="#dataRow39" data-hba-mode="replace" style="">Edit</a>
        <span class="normal" style="">AAA Test 1</span>
        <span class="large" style="">Test Description 1</span>
        <a href="/StateAssociation/Delete/39" class="delete-button" data-hba-ajax="true" data-hba-method="get" data-hba-target="#dataRow39" data-hba-mode="replace" style="">X</a>
    </div>
        <div id="dataRow1" class="list">
            <a href="/StateAssociation/Edit/1" class="x-small action edit-button" data-hba-ajax="true" data-hba-method="get" data-hba-target="#dataRow1" data-hba-mode="replace">Edit</a>
        <span class="normal">AHBA</span>
        <span class="large">Arkansas Home Builders Association</span>
        <a href="/StateAssociation/Delete/1" class="delete-button" data-hba-ajax="true" data-hba-method="get" data-hba-target="#dataRow1" data-hba-mode="replace">X</a>
    </div>
    . . .
</div>
```

[image: Page view after cancelling]

The only difference I can see is those empty `style` tags. They don't appear in the console when I debug my AJAX, and they don't appear in other browsers. But if I manually go in and remove them, it doesn't seem to fix the layout problem.

I realize I've left out a lot of details. I'm trying to keep this from being really excessively long. I can provide any of the missing details if needed. Does anybody have any idea what could be going wrong?

UPDATE: As I'm playing around with this a bit, I have a feeling it has something to do with the `float:right` on the `.delete-button` class. Here's the CSS for that class:

```
.delete-button {
    float: right;
    font-size: .9em;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 3px;
    margin: auto 0;
    color: #888;
}
```